# Time to event = 0 in survival analysis?

Tags: regression, survival, cox-model, censoring

In survival analysis, is it appropriate to have a time to event value of zero for a subject(s). For example, the subject experiences the event on the same date as their date of entry. Does this cause any problem in the usual analytical models e.g. Cox etc.?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Depending on the implementation, software for fitting a Cox regression or other continuous-time survival model might not even accept a survival time of 0. The idea with such models is that you start with 100% survival at `time = 0` and proceed down toward lower survival fractions in continuous time.

In the situation you describe there was survival for at least a fraction of a day, so you could include the actual fraction of the day if available. If that's not known, you might use a small value like 0.5 days for the event time.

For a Cox model the exact time you choose isn't important, as the fitting of the model just proceeds from event time to event time without considering the actual time values of the events. Fitting a parametric model does use the actual time values, but if there aren't many such cases the choice probably won't matter much; you could try different time values for the "0-day" survival times to evaluate how much.

Comment: Thank you @EdM. Would you be so kind as to elaborate on your sentance "...exact time you choose isnt important..." I have another question which I think this might be critical for : https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/604036/cox-model-advice-on-constructing-time-varying-exposure-to-drugs

Comment: @user167591 that's with respect to the time value that you choose to use instead of 0 for first-day events. The Cox model fitting method doesn't use the explicit time values. It just puts the event times in order, starts with the very first event time, and proceeds up through each subsequent event time. From that perspective, whether you choose to call the time of first-day events 0.01 or 0.2 or 0.5 or 0.95 days doesn't matter. The choice will only affect the time displayed for those events at the beginning of a survival curve. Regression coefficients and _p_-values won't be affected.

Comment: Thank you very much as always @EdM!